# Buffergeometry showing up as black with phongmaterial

Tags: three.js

I am trying to render a buffer geometry object using a phong material but it appears as black. I previously used a basic material and it renders correctly. In order to check the lighting I rendered a cube with phong material and it is visible and colored.

I boiled it down to the minimal code which generates the error. I think it may be that I am using the facecolors rather than the vertex colors but I am not sure. What am I doing wrong?

This code works:

```
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x000044});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, material);
cube.position.z = 10;
scene.add(cube);
```

And this code for creating buffergeometry cubes does not:

```
squareMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x0000ff,
    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors
});

for (i = 0; i < verts.length; i += 4) {
    //set 4 points
    a = verts[i];
    b = verts[i + 1];
    c = verts[i + 2];
    d = verts[i + 3];


    for (j = 0; j < a.length; j += 1) {
        a[j] = (a[j] * cubesize) + offsets[j];
        b[j] = (b[j] * cubesize) + offsets[j];
        c[j] = (c[j] * cubesize) + offsets[j];
        d[j] = (d[j] * cubesize) + offsets[j];
    }

    vol.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(a[0], a[1], a[2]));
    vol.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(b[0], b[1], b[2]));
    vol.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(c[0], c[1], c[2]));
    vol.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(d[0], d[1], d[2]));

    idx = i / 2;
    face1 = faces[idx];
    face2 = faces[idx + 1];
    colval = face1[3];

    facecolor = new THREE.Color(colval);

    f1 = new THREE.Face3(face1[0], face1[1], face1[2]);
    f2 = new THREE.Face3(face2[0], face2[1], face2[2]);
    f1.color = facecolor;
    f2.color = facecolor;
    vol.faces.push(f1);
    vol.faces.push(f2);
}
bufferVol = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(vol);
volMesh = new THREE.Mesh(bufferVol, squareMat);
scene.add(volMesh);
```

Comment: Do you have any light sources in your scene?

Comment: when basicMaterial works and others don't it could be wrong or missing normals or missing light-sources.

Answer (score 9):

It was missing the normals. When I called bufferVol.computeVertexNormals(); it the worked. Thanks Martin!

Comment: Thank you for putting an answer to your own question!  I hate it when people find the answer and either never report back or say something to the affect "Nevernind, found it"

Comment: was facing this same issue. thanks for the solution